# Replacing text generator in pytest, handling dynamically generated test values

Tags: python, pytest

How to replace not supported test generators in Pytest? As shown on sample code below, on every loop run diffrent test values are created. I want make every loop run to be treated like separate test. Is there way to somehow use @pytest.mark.parametrize to do that? Using @pytest.mark.parametrize with pre-defined values is easy, but I dont know how handle it when test arguments are generated dynamically.

I need to use pytest on verion > 6, so downgrade is not an option...

```
def check(n,nn):

    assert n==nn, "Failed"   

def test_function(func):

    for arg_1, arg_2 in func.items():
            arg_1 = foo_1(arg_1)
            arg_2 = foo_2(arg_2)
            yield check(arg_1, arg_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. `pytest_generate_tests` hook will help you achieve the same..